# Ajustar tamanho do código de barras Barbecue

Tags: java, código-de-barras

Estou gerando um código de barras utilizando o Barbecue, porém onde vou imprimir o código é em lugar reduzido ou seja o papel tem as dimensões de 8 cm de largura e a informação que tenho que gerar o código de barras tem 44 dígitos.

Já tentei dimensionar meu código gerado mas não consigo.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como estou gerando meu código.

GeradorBarras.java

```
public void GeraCodBarra(String chave) {

    try {
        Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128C(chave);
        barcode.setDrawingText(false);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(50, 75, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        g.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        barcode.setBarWidth(180);
        barcode.setBarHeight(30);
        barcode.draw(g, 10, 56);
        File f = new File("C:/codBarra.png");
        BarcodeImageHandler.savePNG(barcode, f);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.getMessage();
    }
}
```

e o tamanho do código é de 35150648847396000214590000020310033320636124

Obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não conheço uma forma de fazer isto diretamente em um objeto do tipo `Barcode`, já que ele não respeita o *size*, *preferred size*, *minimum size*, etc e nem se ele tem algum utilitário para isto. Olhei na versão 1.5 e não tem.

Uma forma de fazer isto é alterar o tamanho da imagem original que ele gera, recuperando-a a partir do `Barcode`.

Você pode recuperar a `BufferedImage` do objeto `Barcode` desta forma:

```
final BufferedImage originalImage = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);
```

Precisamos agora criar a representação da nova imagem, usando `302` ([valor aproximado equivalente a 8cm](http://www.unitconversion.org/typography/centimeters-to-pixels-y-conversion.html)) de largura e a altura original. Ficaria algo como isto:

```
final int originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

final BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(302, originalHeight, originalImage.getType());
```

Depois precisamos criar a representação gráfica desta imagem e desenhá-la com as novas medidas na nova imagem:

```
final Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, 302, originalHeight, null);
g.dispose();
```

Pronto, aqui já temos a imagem redimensionada, basta então fazer o que for preciso. Para salvar em disco, como você está fazendo, pode fazer assim:

```
final File f = new File("F:/barcode.png");
ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "PNG", f);
```

Um exemplo completo seria este:

```
final Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128C(chave);
barcode.setDrawingText(false);
barcode.setBarHeight(60);
barcode.setBarWidth(2);

final BufferedImage originalImage = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barcode);
final int originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

final BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(302, originalHeight, originalImage.getType());

final Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, 302, originalHeight, null);
g.dispose();

final File f = new File("F:/barcode.png");
ImageIO.write(resizedImage, "PNG", f);
```

Que gerou este código de barras:

[image: Código de barras redimensionado]

A partir deste original:

[image: Código de barras original]

Este é um exemplo e você pode ver outras coisas como escala na nova imagem, você encontrará muita referência na internet de como fazer isto =)

Comment: Ficou irada. Uma duvida no banco de dados a consulta por codigo de barras é comparação de Stream?

Comment: @Krismorte não sei se entendi bem, mas normalmente não são persistidas imagens assim, e sim a informação que a gerou, como uma linha digitável, então a busca seria por esta informação geradora.

Comment: Eu to meio perdido. Como fica a associação do codigo de barras com o registro no banco?

Comment: @Krismorte inclua uma pergunta com suas dúvidas, não há relação com esta questão. Valeu

Comment: Eu criei e me negativaram :(
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133834/gerar-e-ler-c%C3%B3digo-de-barras

Answer (score 0):

Vi em outro post que é possivel definir altura e largura em barcode:

```
barcode.setBarHeight(1200);
barcode.setBarWidth(30);
```

Porém ao jogar na tela ficou "enorme", então baixei os valores de altura para 100 e largura para 3, daí ficou ótimo.